# Was ist das Präteritum von "darben"?

Tags: verb, preterite

Was ist das Präteritum von "darben"?

Folgendes hört sich irgendwie seltsam an:

> Ich habe gedarbt.

Comment: Es hört sich vielleicht deshalb seltsam an, weil das Wort im alltäglichen Sprachgebrauch so gut wie nicht mehr verwendet wird.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/deutsch-englisch/darben.html):

> darben | darbte | gedarbt

That is, Präteritum:

> Ich darbte.

Perfekt:

> Ich habe gedarbt.

Comment: All correct. Though maybe "Ich musste darben" would be a better solution.

Comment: Ah, Perfekt. Leider habe ich keine Stimmen mehr zum upvoten für Heute.